# jQuery animate child element of div relative to window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two div elements; in one element I have child elements that I want to animate to a position on the other div. However when I animate, the child element animates to the position relative to the parent but I would like it to be relative to the window. How is this done?

```
<div class='target'>This is the div I would like to animate to</div>
<div>
    <div class='animateIem'>I want to animate this element to the first div</div>
</div>
```

I animate like this but as I said it animates relative to the parent div not to the window

```
$('.animateItem').animate(top: 100, left: 100);
```

Comment: I have edited code hopefully makes more sense. The target is the sibling of the div containing the item I want to animate.

Comment: `target` will animate with respect to its first ancestor that has a `position` value of anything besides `static`, which is the defaultr.

Comment: Is there a way to make it animate out of the parent though?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have figured out the problem. The element I want to animate needed position absolute.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.animateItem').appendTo(document.body).css("position","absolute").animate({top:100,left:100});
```